# Pass non-dynamic memory allocation to CreateThread() function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, allocation

I pass a address of `USB_INSTACE_DATA` variable to function `CreateThread()` like this. Is it safe to use, or I must use dynamic memory allocation for `USB_INSTACE_DATA` data?

```
DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam);
void GetUSBInfo(PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE pDevInf, WPARAM wParam) {

    USB_INSTACE_DATA data{ pDevInf, wParam };
    DWORD   dwThreadId;
    auto hThreadArray = CreateThread(
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        MyThreadFunction,       // thread function name
        &data,                  // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadId);           // returns the thread identifier
}
```

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text *as text*.

Comment: I have edited images to text @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The code shown doesn't compile, which means that **your** code is different. That difference hides the crucial detail whether `data` has static storage duration or automatic storage duration.

Comment: Unless you have very specific reasons to only use Windows-specific functions, use the C++ standard [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). That will make it *very* easy to pass object by value instead of using pointers.

Comment: Also, if you create a thread, either you need to save it so you can *join* it later, or you need to detach it if it should run totally independent (but be careful when exiting your program, if you want to the thread to keep on working).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That second comment reads: *"Don't use `std::thread`. It's bad. Riddled with crazy gotchas. It's so bad even that we had to supplant it with another type, `std::jthread`"*. Yes, that sounds about right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't safe. `USB_INSTACE_DATA data{ pDevInf, wParam };` has automatic storage duration. Once the enclosing scope ends (i.e. when the function returns), the memory is cleaned up.

The thread launched through `CreateThread`, however, holds a pointer `&data` beyond the function's scope. This is an instance of the classical use-after-free bug.

The solution is to make `data` live at least as long as any client holding a reference/pointer to it. You can use memory with static storage duration, or manual memory management (such as heap allocations). Mind you, this doesn't automagically solve any other issues inherent to concurrent programs such as dealing with data races. That's an issue you will have to address separately.